# If the king is blocked is it checkmate?

Tags: stalemate

If the king is alone and it is blocked is it checkmate? And opponent has blocked with the king and pawn and he did not keep check if we move means that it is check.

Answer (score 1):

if you are to make a move next, and there is no place for your king to move, then its a stalemate. draw.